# BIRT Two dataset and two tables (inner/outer) - Not getting first row value of dataset1 onFetch() in dataset2 - beforeOpen()

Tags: birt

```
Dataset1 - table1 - onFetch()

reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("ID", row["id"]);

Dataset2 - table2 - beforeOpen()

var id = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("ID");
```

In above `dataset2 - beforeOpen()` method not getting first row record value of `dataset1 - table1`....Values starting from **2nd row/record**....last row value getting twice.

Comment: May be check ur query and also query data in designer preview data.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why your approach doesn't work, but it seems too complicated anyway.
You don't need the global variable. Instead, your detail/inner data set (bound to table 2) needs a data set parameter and you can set its value in the data set parameter binding dialog.